# checkboxes inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am using checkboxes inside gridview..  when clicking on the checkbox my code is not getting "IsChecked" value.. here is the code ..

```
protected void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
        string id = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)//loop the GridView Rows
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1"); //find the CheckBox
            if (cb != null)
            {
                if (cb.Checked)...//(showing ischecked=false)///
                {
                    id = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text; // get the id of the field to be deleted
                    sc.Add(id); // add the id to be deleted in the StringCollection
                }
            }
        }
```

I am deleting data from database as..

```
private void DeleteRecords(StringCollection sc)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {
            const string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM User WHERE user_id";
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}='{1}'; ", sqlStatement, item);
        }
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Deletion Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

my asp code is..

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">     
             <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField>
               <HeaderTemplate>
                  <asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="ButtonDelete_Click" />
               </HeaderTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="user_id" ReadOnly="True" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" HeaderText="fname"/>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="lname" HeaderText="lname"/>                
         </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is this WPF? Then please include your WPF code as well.

Comment: Have u write if(!ispostback) in page_load

Comment: can u place the code where you are binding the data for gridivew and also page_Load code

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are binding your grid on Page_Load without checking

```
Page.IsPostBack
```

condition.

```
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
    BindGrid();
```

should solve your problem.